# Javascript injection after domready event is fired

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla

I'm working in a Joomla environment but I think this is not the source of the problem.

I have a view which renders subviews (containing JavaScript code like `<script type="text/javascript></script>`) with AJAX. Problem is : the JavaScript code is ignored. I guess that's because it isn't in the document when it is loaded.

Here's the JavaScript code contained in one of the subview :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        $('annuler').addEvent('click', function() {
            var a = new Ajax(
                    '{$url}', 
                    {
                        method: 'get',
                        update: $('update')
                    }
            ).request();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another basic example, if I load a subview with the following code in it, it won't work either :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        alert('ok');
    }
</script>

<a id="annuler" onclick="test()">Annuler</a>
```

I'm getting the following error message : "test is not defined"

I can't find a solution to that problem so I'm starting to think that it is not a good way to use JavaScript...and, yes, I'm kind of new to event based JavaScript (with frameworks and so on).

Comment: It depends on the JavaScript code that gets injected. Could you show us an example?

Comment: Here it is. This can not work because 'domready' has already been fired, but even if I put a test() function with an alert in it and call it when a link (in the loaded html code) is clicked it will not work...

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you also show us that example `test()` function that does not work?

Comment: What happens with the simple `test()` example when you click the link? Any errors appear in the console? Which browser? You may need to add an `href` attribute to the link for that to work, even with non-injected JS; try using a `<button>` instead of `<a>` for the simple example. Are the "subviews" iframed? Do you have a live link or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (by way of, say, http://jsfiddle.net)? The problem description is still incomplete.

Comment: When I click the link (even if it is a `<button>`) it says "test is not defined". Unfortunately I can't provide any live link. And no, the subviews aren't iframed. It just simply is a PHP page that includes subtemplates and then I replace one of them with the help of Ajax, and in the replacement content there is a link which is supposed to trigger a function which is in a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` block. The JS code that doesn't work only appears after the AJAX call.

Comment: @Matt Ball : I wrote another post with a global description of the situation because I need to see if I'm going in the right direction or not. Maybe it will help you understand what the problem is. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240611/joomla-ajax-forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to put all the subviews and the JavaScript code into the same page. I'm using the CSS `display` property to hide/show a subview (`<div>`) (instead of loading it with Ajax).

Answer (score -1):

Place the code you want to run in a function and call the function from an on ready block

EDIT:
Example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
    });
```

Found here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what a "on ready block" is, could you give me a short example ? (maybe based on the code sample that I added in my original message)

Comment: I'm using mootools, is it the same syntax or if not what is the equivalent ?

Comment: Not sure. Also check out the link that I posted, that might be helpful

Comment: I guess the mootools equivalent is `window.addEvent('domready', function() {});` and it is just what I'm using but the 'domready' or 'ready' event has already been fired when I'm loading the JavaScript code...